# ScrollView not working in LinearLayout

Tags: android-layout, android-scrollview

I am trying to place a linearLayout inside a ScrollView but it isn't working.

Here is my code,

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:background="@color/listChild"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/content_layout">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/alphabet_icon"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/word_text"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/share_button"
                android:id="@+id/share_button"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

            <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/save_new_icon"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/save_button"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:text="Pronunciation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />


            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/speak_icon_2"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/speak_button"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />


        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/pronounciation_text" />




    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:text="Type of Word"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/type_text" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:text="Hindi Meaning"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/hindi_text" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:text="English Meaning"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/english_meaning" />


    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Also, i am using this layout in a fragment in viewPager. And the problem is that the layout is not scrolling.

The layout should look like this,

[image]

Can someone figure out what else am I missing or doing wrong.
And If someone knows a better way to scroll a layout, please tell...

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just use this

> android:fillViewport="true"

inside scrollview tag.. this works for me 
For example

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2">
```

Answer (score 0):

A `ScrollView` is an "infinite" container. It can only know how far you can scroll if it can properly calculate the height of its contents.

Currently you have your `LinearLayout` height set to `match_parent`. This will result in the `LinearLayout` never growing past the height of the `ScrollView` and therefor clipping all the child views.

This is a very long explanation for a very simple **solution: set the `layout_height` of the `LinearLayout` to `wrap_content`.**

Comment: Also, it is scrolling if i use this layout in another **activity** but inside fragment of viewpager it is not scrolling even if i changed every layout into a listview. The listview also not scrolling.